# How to render Redux Container in ReactDOM.render method

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example:

In Link.js

```
class Link extends React.Component {
   ... 
}
export default Link
```

In LinkContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Link from './Link'


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  }
}


const LinkContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Link)

export default LinkContainer
```

In App.js. I have a onClick method to render Link on the fly.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   ...
   onClick() {
      ReactDOM.render(<LinkContainer />,document.getElementById('link1')) //It doesn't work
     // ReactDOM.render(<Link />,document.getElementById('link1')) //It works

   }
}
```

When i render container the error happened

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Link)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Link)

Answer (score 10):

You forgot to set up your [store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html).

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from './redux/reducers/reducer'; // Import your rootReducer here
const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <LinkContainer />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('Link1')
);
```